# Turning a Parcelable object into a POJO with Parcelable child

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I have just started helping out with an exisitng Android project and would like to have as many classes as possible in a "pure" Java module to write jUnit tests against.

However, there are a ton of model objects that all implement `Parcelable` which is an Android class.

Given an existing class

```
package com.example;

public class Foo implements Parcelable {

    //...fields, getter/setters, etc.

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(....) {       
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<T> CREATOR = new ... {
        public T createFromParcel() {...}
        public T[] newArray(int size) {....}
    }
}
```

If I were to split it into two classes (the first [parent] class in the 'pure' java module)

```
package com.example.pure;

public class Foo {
    // ... fields , getters/setters, etc.
}
```

and

```
package com.example;

public class Foo extends com.example.pure.Foo implements Parcelable {
    // all the Parcelable implementation goes here.
}
```

1. Would this cause any problems for the code (presumably in the Android framework) using the `Parcelable` object?
2. Are there factors to consider that could make this a poor choice?